# Можно ли уменьшать высоту PageFooter в зависимости от содержимого? Или как реализовать по другому?

Tags: java, jasperreports, report

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В области PageFooter есть 2 Frame с содержимым, они имеют разную высоту. Печатаются по условию, большой Frame `$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1` только на первой странице, маленький `$V{PAGE_NUMBER} != 1` на всех остальных.
Вопрос, можно ли менять высоту PageFooter, подгоняя под выведенный элемент?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На 2 и последующих страницах остается очень много пустого места. В Detail области еще бы пару строк поместилось. Размещение внизу страницы маленького Frame ничего не дает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если нельзя сделать в jasperreports, то как или с помощью чего можно организовать это (кроме Apache POI)?
Идеальный пример, первый и последующие листы спецификации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
UPD 1. Понятно. Нельзя уменьшить высоту PageFooter:
The page footer band appears on every page where there is a page header. Like the column footer, it is not resizable a run time.
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/report-structure-jaspersoft-studio
Но тогда остается вопрос, как это реализовать в jasperreports?

Answer (score 0):

*UPD 1. Нельзя уменьшить высоту PageFooter* - ошибочен.
Может кому пригодится. Приблизительно я это вижу так.
**Печать**

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("путь к файлу шаблона.jrxml");
KVerticalFiller customVerticalFiller = new KVerticalFiller(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance(), jasperReport);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = customVerticalFiller.fill(parameters, positionsJRBean);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
```

**KVerticalFiller**

```
public class KVerticalFiller extends JRVerticalFiller {
    
    private int pageNumber = 0;
    
    public KVerticalFiller(JasperReportsContext jasperReportsContext, JasperReport jasperReport) throws JRException {
        super(jasperReportsContext, jasperReport);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void addPage(JRPrintPage page) {
        super.addPage(page);
        
        pageNumber++;
        if (pageNumber == 2) {
            try {
                columnFooterOffsetY += pageFooter.getHeight() - 42;
                //42 - высота в пикселях штампа на 2-й и последующих страницах
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**jrxml шаблон**
Код не влез - [ссылка на шаблон](https://github.com/TinoAjato/jrxml-template/blob/main/tst.jrxml).
Использую jasperreports 6.15.0 и itext 2.1.7
**Результат**
[image: Первая страница]
[image: Вторая страница]